# MSAL.Android: Azure Active Directory B2C Authorization with WebView

Tags: android, browser, webview, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Azure Activity Directory B2C authorization on Android is not automatically closing the Browser tab after successfully validating the credentials. Is that an android  limitation or is there any option to programatically close the browser tab?

As per the docs (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/wiki/Migrating-from-MSAL. Android-0.1.n-to-0.2.0), the web-view is supported in msal 0.2+ but  there is no sample provided to do the same. Could you suggest how I can implement B2C authorization using web-view on Android?

Comment: I would open an issue in the [repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues)

Answer (score 1):

The browser tab should close automatically when the auth succeeds and Azure AD B2C calls back to the app. It's possible that app might have been mis-configured or their is a bug in the specific browser you're using (we've seen this before on smaller browsers, so the data could help). With respect to Azure AD B2C, I'd highly discourage using WebViews as Google and other identity providers explicitly disable WebView support.

I'd recommend you to enable logging and share the logs with me and file an issue on the library if needed.

Answer (score 1):

An app can choose to use the in-app WebView by specifying the following line in their configuration JSON passed into MSAL:

"authorization_user_agent" : "WEBVIEW"

instead of:

"authorization_user_agent" : "BROWSER"